# Redirect jsf issue

Tags: redirect, jsf-2

I have a problem redirecting from *a.xhtml* to *b.xhtml*

in **localhost:8080/proyect/a.xhtml?idempresa=2&idcontrato=15** I have this init:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    setIdempresa(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idempresa")));
    setIdcontrato(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idcontrato")));
    ...... }
```

the redirect button is as follow in my view

```
<p:commandButton  action="b.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false" ... />
```

But when I hit the commandButton to redirect it always reload the a.xhtml, with no params as **localhost:8080/proyect/a.xhtml** so it produce

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
>       at beans.MBcompletadoInter.init(MBcompletadoInter.java:83)
>   .....

**MBcompletadoInter is the name of my backing bean which a.xhtml use**

Any advice would be welcome (Y)

Answer (score 0):

b.xhtml?*faces-redirect=true* only works with ajax **enabled**. Are you sure you don't want to use *b.jsf* instead of *b.xhtml*? Can be figured in the web.xml.

Try to use a debug output on *idempresa* and *idcontrato*. What does it print?

Comment: yes its xhtml, but its like the command button refresh the page with no params!

Comment: You have to use ajax in combination with *?faces-redirect=true* to navigate to another page. Are you able to use ajax? If not, why not?
Try to use *b.xhtml?faces-redirect=true* as a return value for your method in *action="#{bean.method}"*, not as an argument for *action="b.xhtml?faces-redirect=true*.

Comment: Or: you can use a simple *p:button* instead of *p:commandButton* as seen here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button.jsf

Comment: yeah It seems that would help, the only thing is that I need to convert to integer since they come as string, I think that should be a big deal! Integer.parseInt() should resolve the issue

Comment: Converting a String into an Integer has nothing to do whether you use p:commandButton or p:button, does it? Does using a "p:button", or using "b.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" as a return value for your action method help solve the problem?